# Check if response contains the whole string in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am getting such html, javascript code response,

```
<td style="width:42px;text-align:center"><a href="/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:Information_icon.svg" class="image" title="Информация"><img alt="Информация" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/35/Information_icon.svg/32px-Information_icon.svg.png" width="32" height="32" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/35/Information_icon.svg/48px-Information_icon.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/3/35/Information_icon.svg/64px-Information_icon.svg.png 2x" /></a></td>
<td style="vertical-align:middle">
<p>Полезно посмотреть на метод <a href="/wiki/Ruby/%D0%A1%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B2%D0%BE%D1%87%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%BA/String#String.23sub.21" title="Ruby/Справочник/String">sub!</a>, который имеет схожую функциональность</p>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
<table class="metadata plainlinks ambox ambox-style">
<tr>
<td class="ambox-image">
<div><a href="/wiki/%D0%A4%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB:Nuvola_apps_important_yellow.svg" class="image" title="⚠"><img alt="⚠" src="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dc/Nuvola_apps_important_yellow.svg/50px-Nuvola_apps_important_yellow.svg.png" width="50" height="42" srcset="//upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dc/Nuvola_apps_important_yellow.svg/75px-Nuvola_apps_important_yellow.svg.png 1.5x, //upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/d/dc/Nuvola_apps_important_yellow.svg/100px-Nuvola_apps_important_yellow.svg.png 2x" /></a></div>
</td>
<td class="ambox-text"><b>Внимание!</b> Данный метод является «опасным», так как изменяет исходный объект. Вместо него рекомендуется использовать метод <a href="#String.23gsub">gsub</a>, который не имеет данного побочного эффекта</td>
<td class="widthhack"></td>
</tr>
<script type="text/javascript">
    //<![CDATA[
    (function(){
        var key = '1c6c249fb3774501aad8e4a2bb177efa';
 //bunch of code
```

how can i check if the response contains the whole key?

```
var key = '1c6c249fb3774501aad8e4a2bb177efa';
```

if i check with include? a part of key it will return true

```
response.include?("1c6c249f") returns true
```

Comment: String#include? is what you need.

Comment: response.include?("1c6c249f") should return false

Comment: Well, check for the whole thing and not a part of it.

Comment: if i check with include? a part of key it will return true, not false

Comment: `response.include?("'1c6c249f'")` (Note the ')

Comment: @spickermann you are right!

Comment: If the response includes the whole key, then it includes any part of the key. It is logically impossible to include the whole key without including parts of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use single quotes in your include method:

```
response.include?("'1c6c249fb3774501aad8e4a2bb177efa'") returns true
```

Then:

```
response.include?("'1c6c249f'")
```

Will return `false`